# How to deduce template type based on another template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction

I have a templated class, whose type is to be determined by another sub templated constructor.

```cpp
template <typename V, typename I>
class Text{
  public:

    template <typename Container, typename V = typename Container::value_type, typename I = typename Container::size_type>
    Text(Container& c) {}

};
```

So usage would be something like:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v;
Text(v) //Deduces to Text<int, std::size_t>
```

Unfortunately, I get an error that V and I are being shadowed. This is because it is trying to create a new V and I.

I have seen a solution with `using V = typename Container::value_type;` but that gives the same error.

Comment: You could parametrize `Text` by a container, not by `V` and `I`, or use a deduction guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your probably want to write your own deduction guide:

```
template <typename Container>
Text(Container&) -> Text<typename Container::value_type,
                         typename Container::size_type>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fdT4TYj77)